# (Kontakt.io) Default password?

Tags: android, ibeacon

i try to change TxPower for mentioned beacon, but when I send hex04 value to TxPower characteristic by android B-BLE application looks like everything is OK, but then I could not see name of becon (default kontakt). Only reset (battery remove) bring name back. From data sheet I read that there is a password but nothing about default password. Have anybody identical issue or know how to solve this one ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your default password for the Beacon is available in Web Panel (https://panel.kontakt.io) in Beacon section.

Best regards,
Rafal

Comment: Thanks, should I create new account or this information is somewhere on the box (heh where is it ?)